Can't submit a question
I try to submit a question, but i get error

This post appears to be a duplicate of Can SRP be used with Elliptic Curves?

If you click on the link, you'll see the question is deleted. Seems to be a bug.

Might be a bug, but for a workaround, as this is one of your questions (and self-deleted), how about editing and then undeleting it?

It can't be undeleted anymore.

Now it is undeleted. A wonder has happened! :D

Well, it has old date and was restored, now it's down and noone reads it. Can i up it somehow?

@SmitJohnth You can edit it to push it back to the top. In general you want to try and add information when bumping but if it's really a bug I guess that's OK?

Edited - it doesn't work.
